# Ruby and Jekyll installation in Linux host without root

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

Can anyone help me installing ruby and jekyll packages in **linux host** under an application account **without root access**?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install ruby on a server where you only have a user account and no root privileges, you can build it from source. [RVM](https://rvm.io/) is a tool that can help with this, that can be installed locally. You may run into issues with missing tools (like a compiler) or dependencies. Depending on what is missing, you may be able to upload it to your user directory some where and continue trying to build ruby. How much work this will be depends on how much is already present on this host.

Although, I will go a bit further and say, if you're planning to use jekyll to generate a static site and server the pages from this linux host, it's probably going to be easier to install ruby and jekyll locally and generate the static site from your development computer, and just upload the results to the server.

Comment: RVM installation is unsuccessful. Getting error message when i execute this command : `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: requesting key 39499BDB from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Keyserver error`
and with this : `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2600:3c03::f03c:91ff:fedb:6957: Network is unreachable`

Comment: I had built static jekyll site successfully in my local machine. Same set up trying to do in linux host

Comment: @Leela why don't you just copy the site to the Linux host?

Comment: to copy and run the site in linux host, i need ruby and jekyll dependencies to be installed

Comment: Jekyll generates a static site, right? So you can just upload the static assets to the server and serve them with Apache or Nginx, or whatever the server has.